# How to create a convex hull with Leaflet points?

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet

Using leaflet, given a set of points, I need to represent the area (polygon) containing all points. 
It's a similar approach of building a bounding box but the result instead of being a rectangle it's a polygon with the external points as vertices.

Perhaps this problem can be fixed on the server side using arcgis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). The easiest way to do this with javascript is to use [Turf.js's `convex` functionality](http://turfjs.org/docs/#convex).

Depending on your data, you might need an [Alpha Shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) instead, which requires more complex algorithms.

Comment: I've updated the question, beside the js library, do you think is better to build convex hull on the server side running arcgis?

Comment: Depends on the use case.

Comment: A simple example is: given a set of cities, the client should show a convex hull/alpha shape for each region.

Comment: Is it faster to generate the convex hulls in the server or the client? Can the clients cope with the computational load of calculating the hulls themselves? How much do you save by doing that? How often are the hulls re-calculated? Does it make sense to pre-calculate everything server-side? That's what I mean by "depends on the use case".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

https://github.com/JohnnyMoonlight/Leaflet-convex-hull

It calculates a convex hull and draws the according polygon. The function showConvexHull() uses an array of leaflet LatLngs, creates a convex hull polygon and adds it to mymap.